# ... can't use '\eqno' in math mode

Tags: equations

texmaker just won't accept my equation, even though all others have been. Does anyone know what's wrong with it ?

```
\begin{equation}  
\label{eq:taillepore}     
\frac{d \theta(r)}{d log__{10} r}  = \frac{d\theta(pF)}{dpF} = \frac{d\theta(h)}{d log_{10}|h|} = \frac{d h}{d log_{10}|h|} \times \frac{d\theta(h)}{dh} = (log_e(10) \times |h| \times \frac{d\theta}{dh}           
\end{equation}
```

[image: The log gives my these errors:]
[image: This is what the equation is supposed to look like]

Thanks a lot !

Comment: You have two underscores `_` in `log__{10}` at the very beginning. There should only be one, and you probably want to use `\log` instead of `log`: `\frac{d \theta(r)}{d \log_{10} r}` etc. pp.

Comment: You can replace the `h` in your equation by `\psi` so it resembles the image you provided better.

Answer (score 3):

mostly not related (problem is solved by [moewe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/35864/moewe) comment) ... i would write your equation with help of packages `amsmath` and `physics` as follows:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{physics}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\label{eq:taillepore}
\dv{\theta(r)}{\log_{10} r}  % <--
    & = \dv{\theta(pF)}{pF}
      = \dv{\theta(\psi)}{\log_{10}|\psi|}
      = \dv{\psi}{\log_{\psi}|h|} \dv{\theta(\psi)}{\psi}  \\
    & = \log_e(10) |\psi| \dv{\theta}{\psi}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```